# What do you call the line between (-2,0) and (0,0) in this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, desmos

When I typed in   $x^2-\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac2y$ on a graphing calculator,

[image]

the graph shows a horizontal segment between  $(-2,0)$ and $(0,0)$. From the graph, I thought that there will be two values of $y$ when $0>x>-2$. But upon testing some numbers, there are no values that lies on that segment.
How does this line formed and why it does not have a value?

Comment: Clearly an error as $y$ cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Desmos (who owns the grapher in question), and here’s the official (and not particularly elucidating) explanation:

> Thanks for sending in a link to your graph.  Dividing by very small
> numbers when we sample sometimes lead to us magnifying tiny errors and
> finding spurious segments. It’s often useful to try writing things in
> a slightly different form and seeing whether that helps. In this case
> it seems to: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kukmx1j4tp
>
> Hope that makes sense and please let us know if you have other
> questions.  Thanks! all the best, [redacted] & Team Desmos